# Prove that: $\sum_{1\le j\le n}{\frac{x_j}{\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i-x_j}}\ge\frac{n}{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> $\color{red}{\textbf{Problem:}}$
>
> Let, $x_i>0,1\le i\le n$, then
>
> **Prove that:**
> $$\sum_{1\le j\le n}{\frac{x_j}{\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i-x_j}}\ge\frac{n}{n-1}$$

$\color{red}{\textbf{Proof:}}$

Using [AM-GM inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20inequality%20of,if%20every%20number%20in%20the) we have,

\begin{align}&\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} (x_i^2+x_j^2)=(n-1)\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i^2\ge 2\left(\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j\right)\\
\implies &\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i^2\ge \frac 2{n-1}\left(\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j\right)\\ 
\implies &\left(\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i\right)^2\ge\left( 2+\frac 2{n-1}\right)\left(\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad =\frac{2n}{n-1}\left(\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j\right)\end{align}

Finally, applying [Cauchy-Schwars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we obtain

\begin{align}\left(\sum_{1\le j\le n}{\frac{x_j}{\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i-x_j}}\right)\left(\sum_{1\le j\le n} \left({x_j}{\sum_{1\le i\le n} x_i-x_j}\right)\right)&\ge \frac{ \left(\sum_{1\le j\le n} x_i\right)^2}{2\left(\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j\right)}\\
&\ge \frac {\frac{2n}{n-1}\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j}{2\sum_{1\le i < j \le n}x_ix_j}\\
&=\boxed {\frac{n}{n-1}.}\end{align}

I need to know if there is something wrong with my solution.

Comment: Your proof seems perfectly fine to me!

Comment: If I were writing this out for a competition or an exam, I would add some detail on how:
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\left(x_j\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i - x_j\right) = 2\sum\limits_{1\leq i < j\leq n}x_ix_j$$

Comment: Mention that $x_j>0$

Comment: I edited the question @peterwhy thank you.

Comment: @Youem Thank you for checking and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's work is correct however $x_j>0$ needs to be mentioned. Here is another approach:

Let $s=\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j,$ then
$$f(x_j)=\frac{x_j}{s-x_j} \implies f''(x)=\frac{2s}{(s-x_j)^3}>0,\quad  0<x_j<s.$$
So by Jensen's inequality
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_j) \ge f(\frac{s}{n}) \implies \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{x_j}{s-x_j}\ge n \frac{s/n}{s-s/n}=\frac{n}{n-1}. $$